# Trying to convert mysqli code to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have this  mysqli code and i am trying to convert it from mysqli to pdo. I have attempted it below but am having trouble with converting it all. can anyone help please?

```
<?php

require_once './config.php';
include './header.php';
include('db.php');
include('database.php');


if($_POST)
{



    mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['amount']);
    $values = str_replace(' ','',$_POST['amount']);
    $values = str_replace('£','',$values);
    $values = explode('-',$values);
    $min = $values[0];
    $max = $values[1];
    $res = mysqli_query($connection,'select `Image`,`recipe_name`,`recipe_price` from recipe where `recipe_price` BETWEEN "'.$min.'" AND "'.$max.'"');
    $count  =   mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $HTML='';
    if($count > 0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $Image       = $row['Image'];
            $recipe_name    = $row['recipe_name'];
            $recipe_price      = $row['recipe_price'];




            $HTML .= '<div>';
            $HTML .= '<br /><img src=images/'.$Image.">";
            $HTML .= 'Name: '.$recipe_name;
            $HTML .= '<br />Price: '.$recipe_price;
            $HTML .= '</div><br /><hr />';

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $HTML='No Recipes Found';
    }
}
else
{
    $min = 0;
    $max = 10;
    $HTML='';
}

?>
```

Could someone help and tell me where i am going wrong in the code below?

```
require_once './config.php';
include './header.php';
include('db.php');
include('database.php');


if($_POST && isset($_POST['amount'])){
$values = $_POST['amount'];

$values = ['£', '', $values];
$values = explode('-',$values);

$min = $values[0];
$max = $values[1];

$sql = "SELECT `recipe_name`, `recipe_price`,  `Image` FROM `recipe` WHERE `recipe_price` BETWEEN "'.$min.'" AND "'.$max.'"");

    $count = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if ($count->fetchColumn() > 0) {
}
while($row = $stmt->fetch(/* PDO::FETCH_ASSOC */)) {
    // do loop stuff
}



    echo $row['recipe']; {

        }

    else
    {

    }
else
{
    $min = 0;
    $max = 10;
    $HTML='';
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which parts of the conversion are you having trouble with?

Comment: Don't make us guess. If you have some reason to think you are going wrong, tell us what it is!

Comment: (1) you never do a `-> query()` on `$ sql` and (2) you should do this with `-> prepare()` and `-> binbParam()` and not directly inject you vars

Comment: You never set `$stmt`.

Comment: this section seems to be throwing up errors $sql = "SELECT `recipe_name`, `recipe_price`,  `Image` FROM `recipe` WHERE `recipe_price` BETWEEN "'.$min.'" AND "'.$max.'"");

Comment: Unrelated to PDO: `$values = explode('-', $values)` is wrong. You set `$values` to an array, the second argument to `explode()` should be a string.

Comment: You need to use the same `str_replace()` code in the new script as the old one to set `$values`.

Comment: Thankyou for all your help i am a beginner so still learning

Comment: plus, make sure you're in fact connecting using PDO when querying with PDO. those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other. we don't know what you're using to connect with.

Comment: i am connecting with pdo using the code: <?php
 //connect to the db
 $confiq = array(
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'username' => 'xxxxx',
  'password' => 'xxxxx',
  'dbname' => 'xxxxxxx',
 );

 $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$confiq['host'].';dbname='.$confiq['dbname'],$confiq['username'],$confiq['password'].'');
?>

Comment: Thanks. I had to be sure. I see many questions where people still keep their old connection methods while switching over to a new MySQL API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `prepare` and `execute` to perform the query. You also had mistakes in how you set `$min` and `$max`, which you rewrote unnecessarily.

```
$values = str_replace(array(' ', '£'), '', $_POST['amount']);
list($min, $max) = explode('-', $values);
$sql = "SELECT `recipe_name`, `recipe_price`,  `Image` 
        FROM `recipe` 
        WHERE `recipe_price` BETWEEN :min AND :max");
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':min' => $min, ':max' => $max));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($rows) > 0) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        // do loop stuff
    }
} else {
    $min = 0;
    $max = 10;
    $HTML = '';
}
```

Comment: let's now hope OP's using PDO to connect with also ;-) Edit: seems that they are. I had to be sure.

Comment: You need a matching `}` after my code.